# Integrating trigonometric functions.

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I need a little help with solving the following two integrals. I am not able to approach these two problems correctly. Little hints will suffice. Thanks for your help!

1. $$\int\frac{\tan^2x\sec^2x}{1+ \tan^6x}\,dx$$
2. $$\int (\sin x \cos x)^{1/3}\,dx$$

Comment: For the first one, substitute $u=\tan^{3}x$.

Comment: 2. has no antiderivative in the known elementary functions.

Comment: Is this question too localized? How could it be improved so that a searcher could find it?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Could you please explain how you concluded that the second integral has no antiderivative in the known elementary functions? Is there a theorem?

Answer (score 1):

- For the first integral, use the fact that $\tan'x=\sec^2x$.
- The second one [cannot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) be [expressed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) in terms of elementary functions. *However*, its definite counterpart can be written in terms of the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), using [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals): $$\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\sin^{2n-1}(x)~\cos^{2m-1}(x)~dx=\dfrac{B(m,n)}2$$ In our case, $m=n=2/3$.

Comment: Could you please explain how you concluded that 'The second one cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions'? Is there a theorem I should know? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @DeepabaliRoy: Were the first two links not clear enough ?

Answer (score 1):

$1.$

$\int\dfrac{\tan^2x\sec^2x}{1+\tan^6x}dx$

$=\int\dfrac{\tan^2x}{1+\tan^6x}d(\tan x)$

$=\int\dfrac{1}{3(1+\tan^6x)}d(\tan^3x)$

$=\dfrac{\tan^{-1}\tan^3x}{3}+C$

$2.$

$\int(\sin x\cos x)^\frac{1}{3}dx=\int\dfrac{\sin^\frac{1}{3}2x}{2^\frac{1}{3}}dx$

Let $u=\sin^\frac{1}{3}2x$ ,

Then $x=\dfrac{\sin^{-1}u^3}{2}$

$dx=\dfrac{3u^2}{2\sqrt{1-u^6}}du$

$\therefore\int\dfrac{\sin^\frac{1}{3}2x}{2^\frac{1}{3}}dx$

$=\int\dfrac{3u^3}{2^\frac{4}{3}\sqrt{1-u^6}}du$

$=\int\dfrac{3u^3}{2^\frac{4}{3}}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(2n)!u^{6n}}{4^n(n!)^2}du$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{3(2n)!u^{6n+3}}{2^{2n+\frac{4}{3}}(n!)^2}du$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{3(2n)!u^{6n+4}}{2^{2n+\frac{4}{3}}(n!)^2(6n+4)}+C$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{3(2n)!u^{6n+4}}{2^{2n+\frac{7}{3}}(n!)^2(3n+2)}+C$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{3(2n)!\sin^{2n+\frac{4}{3}}2x}{2^{2n+\frac{7}{3}}(n!)^2(3n+2)}+C$

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:

Let $u=\tan^3x$.
\begin{align*}
&\int\frac{\tan^2x\sec^2x}{1+\tan^6x}\,dx\\
=&\int\frac{\tan^2x\sec^2x}{1+u^2}\frac{du}{3\tan^2x\sec^2x}\\
=&\frac13\int\frac{du}{1+u^2}\,du\\
=&\frac13\arctan u+C\\
=&\frac13\arctan \tan^3x+C
\end{align*}

Question 2:

Does not look like it has a closed form. Are there any limits?

Comment: Thanks for helping me with the first question. As for the second question, how do I know it is not integrable in this form? You mentioned something about 'closed form'. Could you please explain in more detail? Thanks.

Comment: You can read about the classes of expressions [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression).
The Wolfram (Integrator)[http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=%28Sin%5Bx%5DCos%5Bx%5D%29%5E%281%2F3%29&random=false] solves the second integral using a hypergeometric function.